# If $f^2$ and $f^3$ are smooth, does it follow that $f$ is smooth?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis, derivatives, proof-writing

> Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be given. Assume that the square and cube of $f$ are smooth. Is $f$ smooth? That is if $f \cdot f \in C^{\infty}$ and $f \cdot f \cdot f \in C^{\infty}$, does it follow that: $f \in C^{\infty}$

I got this from another question on SE.

So, $f(x)^2$ is infinitely differentiable, and so is: $f(x)^3$

Also, realize:

$$f(x) = \frac{f(x)^3}{f(x)^2}$$

But what can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is Yes, and the proof is quite technical:

See the answer to this question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/125861/f3-f2-are-the-cube-and-quadratic-of-f-respectively-and-both-infinite-differe

Comment: But how I do that it smooth? Rigourously

Comment: Also I did do that:

$$f(x)  = |x|$$

$$d/dx f(x)^2 = 2x, 2, 0 , 0...$$

$$d/dx f(x)^3 = 3x^2, 6x, 6, 0, 0....$$

Comment: @Amad27: see edit. Sorry to have misled you the first time.

Comment: Do you think this problem is worth being on the Putnam Exam?

Comment: @AMAD27: was this on the putnam?

Comment: It wasn't, I was wondering if it should have been> (+1) By the way

Comment: @Amad27: I think it would be too difficult for the putnam. See Terry Tao's comment in the linked answer.

Comment: that is extremely ironic. Check out here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1169189/is-this-problem-putnam-worthy  Where my question came from