# If $f^2$ and $f^3$ are $C^{\infty}(\mathbb R)$ then $f$ is $C^{\infty}(\mathbb R)$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, taylor-expansion

*Since it is an exercise from an oral exam, I have added some indications I had.*

$f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$, such that $f^2$ and $f^3$ are $C^{\infty}$, show that $f$ is $C^{\infty}$.

The two isolated hypothesis are not sufficient, since there is a problem in zero for the cube root, and since you can take $f$ that takes $1$ and $-1$ without regularity but its square will be constant.

How to proceed with the two hypothesis?

---

Here, the indications I have from the candidate who has taken the oral exam:

-First, show that $f$ is $C^1$:
Suppose $f(0) = 0$ (it is exactly the problem, and by translation we consider that it is in $0$). Suppose they exist and use the Taylor expansions of $f^2$ and $f^3$ up to a non-zero order. Find a polynomial link between both coefficients using equivalents. If they do not exist, $f^2 =o(h^4)$ so $f$ is $C^1$ in $0$ (?).

-Use the general Taylor expansion (with integral remain) for $f^3$.  Suppose the coefficients are not all zeros, (change the bounds to $0$ and $1$), show that the parameter integral is $C^{\infty}$, then take the cube root (??).

Comment: Try $f = f^{3} / f^{2}$

Comment: @DanielLittlewood What is $0/0$, already?

Comment: @Did Here probably 0 for the nominator is a higher-order zero. :)

Comment: @Did $f^{3}=0$ iff $f^{2}=0$ iff $f=0$. So if you define $g = f^{3}/f^{2}$ when $f(x) \ne 0$, and $0$ otherwise, then $g$ will be automatically continuous if $f(x) \ne 0$, and there is a good chance it will be continuous when $f(x)=0$ too (I haven't checked, it was only meant to be a suggestion).

Comment: @DanielLittlewood "there is a good chance" $\ne$ "here is a proof". "continuous" $\ne$ $C^\infty$.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/125861/f3-f2-are-the-cube-and-quadratic-of-f-respectively-and-both-infinite-differe?answertab=oldest#tab-top

Comment: @Did You're right about the notation, that was a mistake. As for your other non-equation, I never made the claim to have a proof, only a suggestion (and not a trivial one either, I don't know why you're upset about it)

Comment: Well, all higher powers of $f$ are certainly $C^\infty$. $f$ is also clearly continuous. $f$ is differentiable on an open, dense set.

Comment: @DanielLittlewood OK. Yes the suggestion is trivial, and it does not work as such. To see the difficulties one runs into when applying it, see the answer below. (But who is upset, by the way? These uncontrolled pop-psychology reductions are frankly a plague.)

Comment: @Lucas, see Terry Tao's comment on the answer to the MO question. It's his own write up of the solution, and it's freely downloadable. I just checked it out. You do need to be able to convert dvi to pdf or something, but there are online converters or if you have latex installed, dvipdf will do the trick.

Comment: Don't see why it would be closed, unless closers pay no heed to context and just care about the question posed... which would really feed into some kind of hypocrisy when they demand context nowadays.

Comment: A $C^{\infty}$ function need  from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R$ can fail to have a power-series expansion. For example if $f_n(c_n)=0$ and $f_n(x)=a_n \exp (-b_n^2(x-c_n)^{-2})$ for $x\ne c_n.$ consider $\sum_{n\in \Bbb N}f_n(x)$ for a suitable choice of the $a_n,b_n,c_n.$

Comment: A problem like this is a bit unreasonable for an oral exam...far too difficult

Comment: Duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1170033/if-f2-and-f3-are-smooth-does-it-follow-that-f-is-smooth

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This result was first proved in:

1. Henri Joris, *Une $C^\infty$ application non-immersive qui possède la propriété universelle des immersions*, Arch. Math. (Basel), **39**, 269-277, 1982.

The proof we provide follows the general framework of the proof which appears in:

2. Robert Myers, *An Elementary Proof of Joris's Theorem*, Amer. Math. Monthly, **112**, no. 9, 829-831, 2005.

We shall use the following notation
$$
P_{n,x_0}(x;F)=F(x_0)+F^{(1)}(x_0)(x-x_0)+\frac{F^{(2)}(x_0)}{2!}(x-x_0)^2
+\cdots+\frac{F^{(n)}(x_0)}{n!}(x-x_0)^n.
$$
where $F$ is a function $n$ times differentiable in some open interval $(a,b)$ 
containing $x_0$. We shall be using the following lemmata:

**Lemma 1.** *Let $F: (a,b)\to\mathbb R$ be a function possessing all derivatives up to order $n$, for some $x_0\in(a,b)$. 
$F^{(1)}(x_0),\ldots,F^{(n)}(x_0)$. Then*
$$
\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{F(x)-P_{n,x_0}(x;F)}{(x-x_0)^n}=0.
$$

*Proof.* See Spivak.

**Lemma 2.** *Let $\,F: (a,b)\to \mathbb R\,$ be function which is $k$ times differentiable in $(a,b)$ and $k+1$ times differentiable in $(a,b)\setminus\{x_0\}$, where $x_0\in(a,b)$. If
$$
L=\lim_{x\to x_0} \frac{F(x)-P_{k,x_0}(x;F)}{(x-x_0)^{k+1}} \in\mathbb R,
$$
then $f$ possesses derivative of $k+1$ order at $x_0$, and
$F^{(k+1)}(x_0)=(k+1)! L.$*

*Proof.* Use L' Hôpital's Rule.

**Lemma 3.**
*Let $F\in C^{k+n}(a,b),\,$ $x_0\in(a,b),\,$ and
$$
G(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ccl}
\dfrac{F(x)-P_{k,x_0}(x;F)}{( x-x_0)^{k+1}} & \text{if} & x\ne x_0, \\
(k+1)! F^{(k+1)}(x_0) & \text{if} & x= x_0, \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$
then $G\in\ C^n(a,b)$. In particular, if $\,F\in C^\infty(a,b)$, then $\,G\in C^\infty(a,b)$.*

*Proof.* Use induction on the degree of 
$P_{k,x_0}$ and evoke Lemma 2.

***Proof of Joris's Theorem.***  Let us first note that, 
if $f(x_0)\ne 0$, for some  $x_0\in\mathbb R$, then $f$ maintain sign in a whole
open interval $I$, with $x_0\in I$, and as $h=f^3$ is $C^\infty$ in $I$, then $f$ is also $C^\infty$ in $I$, as the composition of $x^{1/3}$,
which is $C^\infty$ in $\,\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}\,$ and $f^3$. The hard part is to show that $f$ is $C^\infty$, where $f$ vanishes. We set 
$$
Z=\{x\in\mathbb R: f(x)=0\}
$$ 
and let $\,x_0\in Z$. We shall study separately the cases where
$x_0$ is an isolated point of $Z$ from the case where $x_0$ is an accumulation point of $Z$.

It is important to point out that, in order for $f^{(k+1)}(x_0)$ to be definable, $f$ has to be $k$ times differentiable in an interval containing $x_0$.

**Case A.** *$x_0$ is an isolated point of $Z$.*

**First sub-case.** *$\,h^{(n)}(x_0)=0,\,$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$.*

We shall show in this sub-case that all the derivatives of $f$ exists
at $x=x_0$ and they all vanish.
Due to *Lemma 1* we have that
$$
0=\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{h(x)}{(x-x_0)^n}=\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f^3(x)}{(x-x_0)^n}, \quad 
\text{for all $n\in\mathbb N$,}
$$
since $P_{n,x_0}(x;h)\equiv 0$. Hence $\,\displaystyle\lim_{x\to x_0}\dfrac{f(x)}{(x-x_0)^n}=0$, for all $n\in\mathbb N$. 
In particular
$$
\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}=\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f(x)}{x-x_0}=0,
$$
and therefore $f$ is differentiable at $x=x_0$, and $f'(x_0)=0$. We shall show inductively that, for every $n\in\mathbb N$,the function $f$ is $n$ times differentiable at $x=x_0$ and $f^{(0)}(x_0)=f^{(1)}(x_0)=\cdots=f^{(n)}(x_0)=0$.  Assume that this is true for some $\,k\in\mathbb N$. 
Then $P_{k,x_0}(x;f)\equiv 0$ and thus *Lemma 2* provides that $f$ is $k+1$ differentiable at $x=x_0$ and $f^{(k+1)}(x_0)=0$.

**Second sub-case.** *There exists an $\,n\in\mathbb N$, such that $\,h^{(n)}(x_0)\ne 0$.*

Let $k$ be the least positive integer, such that $\,h^{(k)}(x_0)\ne 0$. 
*Lemma 3* provides that, there exists a function $\,H\in C^\infty(\mathbb R)$,
such that $\,h(x)=(x-x_0)^kH(x)$, with $H(x_0)\ne 0$. In particular, there exists an interval $\,(a,b)$, with $x_0\in (a,b)$, where $H$ maintains sign. 
Meanwhile we have that
$$
g^3(x)=h^2(x)=(x-x_0)^{2k}H^2(x),
$$
and hence,
$$
g(x)\big(H^2(x)\big)^{-1/3}=\big((x-x_0)^{3k}\big)^{1/3},
\quad\text{for all $x\in (a,b)$}.
$$
The right hand side of the above is $C^\infty$ in $(a,b)$, which implies that $2k/3$ is an integer, and hence $k=3k_1$, for some positive integer $k_1$. Thus
$h(x)=(x-x_0)^{3k_1}H(x)$, and consequently 
$$
f(x)=(x-x_0)^{k_1}H^{1/3}(x),
$$
and hence $f$ is $C^\infty$ in $(a,b)$.

**Case B.** *$x_0$ is an accumulation point of $Z$.*

In such case, there exists a sequence $\,\{x_n\}\subset Z$, such that $x_n\to x_0$. We may assume that this sequence in strictly monotone. Without loss of generality we assume that $\{x_n\}$ strictly increasing. Then
$$
0=h(x_1)=h(x_2)=\cdots=h(x_n)=\cdots.
$$
Due to Rolle's Theorem, there exist $\xi_i \in(x_i,x_{i+1})$, such that
$$
0=h'(\xi_1)=h'(\xi_2)=\cdots=h'(\xi_n)=\cdots.
$$
Thus $\,h'(x_0)=0$, since $h'$ is continuous and $\xi_n\to x_0$. Repeating the same procedure for $h'$ instead of $h$, we obtain that $h''(x_0)=0$, and 
inductively that $\,h^{(n)}(x_0)=0$, for all $n\in\mathbb N$.

As in the study of the *First sub-case*, we obtain, by virtue of *Lemma 1*, that 
$$
0=\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{h(x)}{(x-x_0)^n}=\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f^3(x)}{(x-x_0)^n}, \quad 
\text{for all $n\in\mathbb N$,}
$$
and thus
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}=\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f(x)}{x-x_0}=0.
\end{equation*}
Therefore, $f$ is differentiable at $x=x_0$, and $f'(x_0)=0$. Next, we shall show inductively that $f$ possesses derivatives of all orders at $x=x_0$, and that they all vanish. Combining all the studied cases so far we have that $f$ is differentiable in the whole of $\mathbb R$. We shall use induction to prove our claim.

Assume that $f$ is $k$ times differentiable in $\mathbb R$ and also
$$
f^{(0)}(x_0)=f^{(1)}(x_0)=\cdots=f^{(k)}(x_0)=0,
$$
in every $x_0$, which is an accumulation point of $Z$. Then $f$ is $k+1$ times differentiable in the whole of $\mathbb R$, and $f^{(k+1)}(x_0)=0$, for every $x_0$, which is an accumulation point of $Z$. We have that 
$$
\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f(x)}{(x-x_0)^n}=0,
$$
for every $x_0$ which is an accumulation point of $Z$, and by virtue of *Lemma 2*,
$f$ possesses derivative of order $k+1$ in every such $x_0$. Combining all the studied cases we obtain that $f$ is $k+1$ times differentiable in the whole of $\mathbb R$. This establishes the induction hypothesis and completes the proof of Joris's Theorem.

**Note.** This proof can be easily generalised for the case when $\,f^k,f^\ell\in C^\infty(\mathbb R)$ and $(k,\ell)=1$.

Answer (score 1):

This is not really an answer, I've posted this as a comment on the question above, I just think the information needs to be more prominently displayed for future viewers.

On the answer to the [MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/125861/69100)  addressing this, Terry Tao commented with the following link to his write up of the solution to the problem based on one of the papers in the answer: http://www.math.ucla.edu/~tao/preprints/Expository/squarecube.dvi.
To convert dvi to pdf, see [this tex.SE answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/165636/35255).

Answer (score 0):

The obvious thing is to consider $$g=\begin{cases}f^3/f^2,&(f^2\ne0),\\0,&(f^2=0).\end{cases}$$It's not hard to show that $g$ is continuous: If $f^2\ne0$ and $|f^2|<\epsilon$ then $|g|<\epsilon^{1/2}$. One can imagine showing "directly" that $g^{(k)}$, defined at first on the set $f^2\ne0$, extends continuously to $\Bbb R$, but it seems like things are going to get worse and worse as $k$ increases.

The point to this non-answer is to point out that at least one approach to a more elegant solution cannot work: For a little while I thought about looking for a smooth function $F(x,y)$ such that $$F(t^2,t^3)=t.$$But that's impossible; differentiating gives $$2tF_x(t^2,t^3)+3t^2F_y(t^2,t^3)=1,$$which implies $0=1$.

Comment: In some sense, $F = \frac{x}{y}$, the function you use to define $g$, except for $t = 0$.

Comment: Well of course $F=x/y$ works, except it's not smooth.

Comment: Probably $y/x$, not $x/y$.